# Read array of integers from user which is separated by space in C#

Tags: c#, space, separator

I was asked to solve a problem in C# to get the sum of 'n' user inputs from console, which is separated by space, in a single line.

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[n];
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   sum += arr[i];
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}",sum);
```

How can I modify this code to get the expected output from the space separated input?
Also the values need to be stored in array.

Input:

5

1 2 3 4 5

Output:

15

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @Some1Pr0 Problem at storing array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int result = input.Split(' ').Take(n).Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

But it seems to me that you could avoid asking the user for the count, and just add together all the lines that they typed in:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int result = input.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

(Note that this code does no error checking.)

EDIT: It seems that you want to have an array of ints. In that case, you can do it like this (again, with no error checking):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Take(n).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            int sum = arr.Sum();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\naveenkumar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HackerRank\HackerRank\Program.cs 17 48 HackerRank

Comment: @NaveenKumarV You have to do `using System.Linq`

Comment: I just add that if you want to get more than one line from the user you have to set a Loop (like a while) to collect the strings and then calculate the sum when the user exits the loop.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs It seems he wants the data typed all on one line.

Comment: @all. Thanks for your kind efforts to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
int result = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

You'll of course have to handle any bad user input as needed.

Per your added requirements:

```
int[] items = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int sum = items.Sum();
```

Comment: No, I want to store the separated values into array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the split function in C#. When you read the line, you get the whole line. This means you're attempting to say "sum = 0 plus Convert.ToInt32('5 1 2 3 4 5')" which doesn't work.

You need an array of integers equal to 
    Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");

String.Split function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: Not to mention that since you are reading in user input, you have to guard against trying to sum "1 2 3 foo bar". I believe convert throws an exception with string input.

Answer (score 0):

using  arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) inside the loop will cause the program to expect an input on a different line and not on a single line.
What you can do is to take the input as a string and then split based on space, which produces an array of the inputed values. You can then sum them

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that Naveen seems a student, I think some more code can explain better and let him learn some more from this exercise:

I've made a sample that gets some numbers separated by space or an enter and when the user enters a T calculates the sum in a traditional way using a loop and using Linq. I'm sure there are plenty of better ways to do the same, but maybe something a little bit more structured can be better to begin understanding C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SumTheNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Insert the numbers separated by a space or [Enter]> key, when finished write T and press [Enter] and you will have the result");
            List<int> values = new List<int>();
            while (true)
            {
                string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
                if (inputData.ToUpper().StartsWith("T")) break;
                string[] svals = inputData.Split(' ');

                for (int i = 0; i < svals.Length; i++)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    int.TryParse(svals[i], out x);
                    if (x != 0) values.Add(x);
                }



            }

            //Traditional mode
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                total = total + values[i];
            }

            //Linq mode

            int totalLinq = values.Sum();

            Console.WriteLine("The sum is");
            Console.Write("Total: ");
            Console.WriteLine(total.ToString());
            Console.Write("Total linq: ");
            Console.WriteLine(totalLinq.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to end...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```