# Get the multiple integers from user

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C# and I have a problem with the get the input from the user and this is the requirements:

Get a list of integer numbers from the user on A SINGLE LINE

- The numbers will be in the range [0,100]
- The numbers will be separated by spaces
- You may assume that the user enters a correctly formatted input string that meets these requirements
- You may use Console.ReadLine or a similar method to get input from the user

And here is my code

```
//Prompt the input from user
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numbers in the range [0,100]: ");
int n;
n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[n];
string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Int32.Parse(s[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(n);
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    Console.Write(item+ " ");
}
```

These are the errors I got and I try to fix but it still does not work.

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Please show an example of the inputs (two lines) that creates the error

Comment: You are `ReadLine()`ing twice. The first time, when the user has provided you with a string, you are trying to parse it as an int.

Comment: @Jonathan the first ReadLine is supposed to read the number of the integer elements in the following ReadLine so it is expected to be a number that can be read as an integer

Comment: Also, if 'You may assume that the user enters a correctly formatted input string that meets these requirements', then all you need to do is split the input on space (unless you need to verify the input is between 0 and 100)

Comment: @Aiden You mean with the first `ReadLine` you are trying to get the required length of the array? When you do your `Split` you'll have the length. Until then, you won't

Comment: There is nothing in the instructions that calls for getting, as input from the user, the number of integers to be entered by the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read array of integers from user which is separated by space in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610661/read-array-of-integers-from-user-which-is-separated-by-space-in-c-sharp) - maybe the same class? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the input into the int variable.
Instead read that to a variable and then use string split to get an array, from there you only need to iterate the array.
For instance:

```
            //Prompt the input from user
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numbers in the range [0,100]: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var inputArray = input.Split(' ');
            foreach (var item in inputArray)
            {
                Console.Write(item+ " ");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numbers in the range [0,100]: ");
List<int> IntList = new List<int>(); 
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var array = input.Split(' ');
foreach (var item in array)
{
    IntList.Add(Int32.Parse(item);)
}
IntList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```